# How to checkout additional projects or directorys using tortoiseSVN after first checkout?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I create a new directory, go into it, right click and select "SVN checkout" to checkout one of several projects under that directory, how can I later checkout another project under a subdirectory under the same directory, using the same .svn folder?

The problem being that after I checked the first project out, there is no longer a "SVN Checkout" right click option.  Also the first subdirectory (that is above where the new project goes) already contains a .svn folder

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but see no reason why it shouldn't work. Checkout the supposed second working copy outside of the first, and just move the folder into the parent working copy. Also add that new working copy folder to [ignore list](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html).

But the solution above only makes sense if you want to keep the two projects separated. If however you want to maintain in the repository this relation between the two folders then you should add appropriate `svn:externals` property to the parent folder.